# Kinect Finger Detection and Tracking With Face Involved

Tags: c#, kinect, emgucv

I'm stuck in a phase in my Final Year Project where I require to calculate the coordinates of fingers on different facial features (nose, eyes or chin) of the user performing the gesture(s).

I've been able to extract the fingers and the recognition works good. I'm using Emgucv .Net wrapper for Open Cv to apply contouring and convex hull on the hands and fingers. The program works well when I just have hands and fingers in the threshold range but whenever I place the fingers near the face or include the face in the threshold area then the contoured area also includes the face and the finger tip points become invalid.

Is there anyway that I can just segment the fingers and hands in the desired threshold even though the face is present in the zone?
Or should I lose contouring technique completely and use something else?

Comment: This sounds like one of those problems: http://xkcd.com/1425/. You want to separate the fingers from the face, which will be hard. In the color image, the fingers will have the same color as the face. In the depth image, the noise from the face will most likely overwhelm any information about the fingers. But maybe not. Are you using Kinect v1 or v2? And what's the distance of the face to the sensor?

Comment: Kinect v1 and the face and hands should be at a distance of around 3-4 feet from the kinect sensor. For my current technique I have to bring the fingers a lot close to make them the biggest contour present in front of the sensor, if i move them back, the face gets contoured as well.